# Unplugging Razer Deathadder mouse before it is done setting up

Tags: mouse

I plugged my mouse into the wrong USB port after I unplugged it. When I realized I quickly switched it to the one it was previously in. I unplugged it while it said setting up device. Will this cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

No. USB is meant to install a driver everytime the device is plugged in, and plugging it in is bound by port.

So if you plug in a driver and unplug it, the installation continues on the background but the driver is not used. If you then plug it into the port you always do, it detects the old driver for that port and skips installation.

Rule of thumb is: if a device does not work on one USB port, you can always try to plug the device in another port so it reinstalls the drivers.